# Selenium invalid selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, bots

Hi I'm not a strong coder, but can you help me with my problem, I can't find solution.
Some changes happened in selenium the last relize, and my bot returned errors.
It's my code

```
page_ig = input("Enter page username: ")
browser.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{page_ig}")
sleep_for_period_of_time()

followers_link = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul/li[2]/a")
followers_link.click()
sleep_for_period_of_time()

num_follow = input("How many person you want to follow:")

while(True):
    try:
        i = 0
        list_of_followers = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button/div/div[contains(text()  "Follow")]')
        for person in list_of_followers:
            if person.text == "Follow":
                person.click()
                print("Followed!")
                i += 1
                print(i)
                sleep_for_period_of_time()
            else:
                pass
            if i >= int(num_follow):
                break
```

it returns me error:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button/div/div[contains(text()  "Follow")] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button/div/div[contains(text()  "Follow")]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.98)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x555b36ed02a3 <unknown>
#1 0x555b36c8ef77 <unknown>
#2 0x555b36c929c8 <unknown>
#3 0x555b36c92792 <unknown>
#4 0x555b36c92a9c <unknown>
```

or i added some changes to code it return me list out of the range

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid XPath expression `'//button/div/div[contains(text()  "Follow")]'`
Probably it should be

```py
'//button/div/div[contains(text(), "Follow")]'
```

So, the Selenium code line will be:

```py
list_of_followers = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button/div/div[contains(text(), "Follow")]')
```

Comment: try changes (By.XPATH, '//button/div/div[contains(text(), "Follow")]')

Comment: and (By.XPATH, '//button/div/div[contains(text() = "Follow")]') doesn't wor

Comment: Add the `HTML` source if the above answer did not work for you.